# MySQL equation(WHERE clause)

Tags: mysql, domo

I am trying to use create a graph using last months sales (plus 10% of last months production so multiplying the last months sales by 1.1). It seems it should be simple but I can't seem to figure it out, I have tried using a CASE statement

```
CASE
   WHEN MonthName(SaleDate) = 'Jan' THEN Count(SaleId) -- how do we limit for a particular time frame in a CASE?
```

I am using the MySQL version 5.7, but  I am using DOMO so I can't be sure but 5.7 was the documentation they linked to

Comment: You probably want `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` rather than `CASE WHEN ... SUM(...)`

Comment: Or if you're only processing the January sales, put that in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN MonthName(SaleDate) = 'Jan' THEN SaleAmount END) "January Sales)
FROM my_table
```

**NB**

- If you don't specify the year you could have the total of sales from January 2021 + January 2022.
- I assume that the column salesId is not the value of the sale.
- I suspect that the function `month()` could run faster than `monthname()`. `WHEN MONTH(SaleDate) = 1`